# QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled on Ubundu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt4

I am trying to load QT application which have some 3D graphics, application works on two Linux PC(where QT ) but on third one(new PC) this error is showing.

```
"QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled"
```

I tried to install

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

and added soft link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 libGL.soudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 libGL.so
```

Machine Configuration

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:30 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Please guide,any input is a great help.